# How to merge vertices to form a coarse mesh?

Tags: graph, graphics, 3d, open3d, trimesh

I have a garment trimesh (python `trimesh` library), and want to uniformly select about half of the vertices and use these vertices to form a coarse garment mesh (still triangle mesh). The correspondence between the vertices of the original mesh and the coarse mesh is necessary.
For now, I have obtained the corresponding relationship perm like below, but I don't know how to use the obtained vertices to form a new mesh.

```
radius = np.sqrt(gar_restPose_mesh.area / (2 * vertC1_num))
coarse_gar_verts, mask = trimesh.points.remove_close(ori_gar_verts, radius)
perm = np.argwhere(mask).flatten()
```

Do you have any idea? Or a new pipeline to achieve this?

---

I have also tried to use

```
_, face_indices = trimesh.sample.sample_surface_even(gar_mesh, coarse_gar_vert_num)
coarse_gar_mesh = gar_restPose_mesh.submesh([face_indices])[0]
```

, but the result is not a correct garment, see this image.
[image]